# python: ImportError: No module named patheffects

Tags: python, matplotlib

When i try to run a python script in which i do an import statement matplotlib.patheffects, i get an error message saying there is no module called patheffects.
the statement is 
import matplotlib.patheffects

Kindly help me to figure out the reason for this error and how to make the code run without this glitch.

Comment: I just looked briefly at the `matplotlib` docs and couldn't find `patheffects`.  Is it a module, package, function, other object? [Edit] Found it.

Comment: What version of `matplotlib` do you have? (For others trying to help: `patheffects` is a module)

Comment: either from matplotlib import patheffects or import matplotlib.patheffects are working for me in winXP

Answer (score 2):

`import matplotlib.patheffects` works perfectly well for me. Please make sure you have [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) installed. The most current version is `1.0.1`. You can download from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/).

Matplotlib depends on [numpy](https://numpy.org/), so make sure you have it installed before installing matplotlib.

Also check out the tips on [installing matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html).